# Google Blockly - message0 linebreak / vertical space

Tags: google-blockly

I am creating a Google Blockly block with several checkboxes regarding date periods

[image: Current situation]

As this is very wide, I'd like to split it up into smaller sections.
Specifically, it would be great if after `Sunday` it would put `Holiday` on a new line.

I've looked around and discovered `inputsInline` `false` should stack vertical, however it does not appear to do anything for me.

```
{
  "type": "block_type",
  "message0": "%1 Monday %2 Tuesday %3 Wednesday %4 Thursday %5 Friday %6 Saturday %7 Sunday %8 Holiday %9 Bridge day %10 Vacation %11 Exceptional Period %12 Normal day",
  "args0": [
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "MONDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "TUESDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "WEDNESDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "THURSDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "FRIDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "SATURDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "SUNDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "HOLIDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "BRIDGEDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "VACATION",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "EXCEPTIONALPERIOD",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "NORMALDAY",
      "checked": true
    }
  ],
  "inputsInline": true, // Tried false as well
  "output": "Boolean",
  "colour": 120,
  "tooltip": "",
  "helpUrl": ""
}
```

Is there an easy way to make this more readable?

Answer (score 1):

`inputsInline` orders different inputs under one another, so I had to split them.

```
{
  "type": "block_type",
  "message0": "%1 Monday %2 Tuesday %3 Wednesday %4 Thursday %5 Friday %6 Saturday %7 Sunday",
  "message1": "%1 Holiday %2 Bridge day %3 Vacation %4 Exceptional Period %5 Normal day",
  "args0": [
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "MONDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "TUESDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "WEDNESDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "THURSDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "FRIDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "SATURDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "SUNDAY",
      "checked": true
    }
  ],
  "args1": [
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "HOLIDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "BRIDGEDAY",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "VACATION",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "EXCEPTIONALPERIOD",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "type": "field_checkbox",
      "name": "NORMALDAY",
      "checked": true
    }
  ],
  "inputsInline": false,
  "output": "Boolean",
  "colour": 120,
  "tooltip": "",
  "helpUrl": ""
}
```